# Spring XML created bean is not able to see @Service Bean

Tags: xml, spring, configuration

I have a Spring project in which I use both XML and Java Configuration.

The issue is that a bean created in the Spring XML file is not able to see a bean created by annotations. But a bean created with annotations is able to see a bean created in the xml file.

Do you know any (technical) reason for this?

Comment: Could you provide more details? Does your application use WebMVC? How many `.xml` files in your application?

Comment: I have just one xml file. I am using Spring MVC. The problem is that the bean created in the xml file is not able to see the bean created with @ Service. So I can't inject the bean @ Service to the bean created in the xml file. Any reason for this?

Comment: Can you add text of xml config to your question?